# Create setup for Outlook 2010 Add-in

Tags: .net, outlook, installation, add-in

I have created a outlook add-in and need to create  a setup to make it distributable (i am new to this so pls excuse the novice comments )

```
Outlook -2010
Vs  -2010
.Net 4.0
```

I read some where ,the easiest way to do this would be to just publish. And yes it was that easy. The setup was created and i could install.
The catch ,was that  in systems which did not have .net 4.0 (or maybe VS 2010), the setup began installing the framework first (which is good .. :))  on restarting system (on complete installation of 4.0).
When user tries to install the setup it gives error saying :

> the following solution cannnot be loaded because Microsoft Office
>   support for the .Net framework 4.0 is not installed

The users machine had Outlook 2010 and framework 3.5 initially. I checked and 4.0 client was installed (33 MB approx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I experienced the same issue recently and had to install Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime on the client workstations before installing my add-in. After installing it I was immediately able to install my add-in without a reboot.

According to this [post][3] from the VSTO team:

> Note that in the Beta and RTM
>   releases of Office 2010 you will NOT
>   get Office 4.0 Runtime Extensions (or
>   the capability for them to be “turned
>   on”). If you are deploying
>   customizations that target .Net
>   Framework 4 and they will run on
>   Office 2010 you will need your users
>   to install the VSTO 2010 Runtime
>   redistributable (and of course before
>   their customization will run they will
>   have to install .Net Framework 4).

Answer (score 2):

You may edit Project's property page and select packages you want them to get installed before your application and you may also ask the publisher to include these required files, locally, with your installation package.

just check out the "Prerequisites" button on the "Publish" tab.

BTW, make sure you change .Net 4 Client Profile to .Net 4.0 and include Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime.